# Can I take off the gas deflector on my stove for cooking with a wok?

Tags: equipment, wok, gas

This question might be Off-Topic, due to the gas involvement, although it is equipment related, but I'll see what people think.

I have a gas stove top, and I like to cook with a wok.  But the gas deflectors that are used to make the nice 'ring' of gas for flat bottoms pans mean the heat source is dissipated for my wok, and when I have worked in chinese restaurants in the past they generally have a single ruddy great flame in the middle that their woks go over.

Could I remove the deflectors and just burn the gas coming directly from the hole underneath so I got the single large flame under my wok that I'm after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard of anyone trying this. I think its very unlikely though. Those gas deflectors are actually specially designed to pull in the appropriate amount of atmospheric air for a proper flame. This is why the flame you see is so blue and has very little orange.

I'd look into seeing if there is some way to get a replacement deflector that is better suited for wok cooking.

You could also do what Alton Brown does and use the bottom half of a turkey deep fryer, outside preferably, and not over any pipes or electrical wiring or gravel.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your stove.  I used to do this when I would wok at home.  My stove had the cast iron deflectors as you describe them, but the hob part had the center missing.  So if you took the deflector off you would get a very strong blue flame coming out of the burner hitting the wok where it should, the very bottom center of the wok.

The problem is if you decide to lift and flip the wok.  Any wind or movement will disrupt the flame and possibly make it go out.  The deflector is also there to make the flame not susceptible to wind or movement. So I often would just leave the wok on the burner and use both the ladle and the turner together to keep the food from burning.

Another problem with actually getting more fire power, is that you need to have the proper ventilation.  Once you increase the fire,you will increase the smoke and heat, and that will quickly fill your kitchen with smoke.  So having a vent that is strong enough to pull it out or having lots of windows and a fan to blow that smoke out of your house is essential.  Also fire alarms tend to go off at this time as well.